# Dealing with iPhone 6/6+ startup images

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-6

I used to simply work with two screen sizes, but now after the new **iPhone 6/6+** are announced I need to deal with four screen sizes, So How could I specify the **startup images** for these **new** devices ??

Thanks in advance

---

#### Update

[image]

In **.xcassests** file I found new settings added in **Xcode 6 GM** which is (**Retina HD 5.5**) and (**Retina HD 4.7**), I guess it's easy to find which one is for iPhone 6 and which for iPhone 6+ but what's the name for these startup images by default ??

because I don't usually work with **.xcassests** file

```
3.5 inches = Default.png
(320px x 480px)

3.5 inches (with retina) = Default@2x.png
(640px x 960px)

4.0 = Default-568h@2x.png
(640px x 1136px)

4.7 = ??
(750px x 1334px)

5.5 = ??
(1242px x 2208px)
```

---

## The Answer:

After some search later, I found the following answer:

```
3.5 inch screen: LaunchImage-700@2x.png
4.0 inch screen: LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png
4.7 inch screen: LaunchImage-800-667h@2x.png
5.5 inch screen: LaunchImage-800-Portrait-736h@3x.png
iPad2          : LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png
Retina iPads   : LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
```

Comment: The device should just automatically scale up the existing ones...

Comment: @rebello95 I would like to design a startup image for iPhone 6/6+ without scaling the old ones, for better resolution .. as what we were doing for iPhone 5

Comment: Good point. I don't currently have Xcode 6 GM installed, but I'd see if there are new sets in the `.xcassets` file.

Comment: The iPhone 6 launch image is 750 x 1334, not 640 x 1136.

Comment: Are you use image assets for the launch images?

Comment: Your update is for regular images, not launch images.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for notifying me, but I still didn't find the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can name them whatever you want, you just have to make sure they are in your plist, and that you don't specify the extension or @2x or @3x suffix in the plist. The files in your Xcode project should have the .png and @2x or @3x extension. The size is always specified in portrait mode (even for landscape images).

This has the added benefit of not using the asset catalog and allowing you to easily load the png in your app to do a custom transition from the splash screen to your app.

Here's an example from my app, [You Doodle](http://bit.ly/YouDoodleApp):

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key><string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key><string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key><string>{320, 480}</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key><string>Default</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key><string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key><string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key><string>{320, 568}</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key><string>Default-568h</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key><string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key><string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key><string>{768, 1024}</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key><string>Default-Landscape</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key><string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key><string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key><string>{768, 1024}</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key><string>Default-Portrait</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key><string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key><string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key><string>{414, 736}</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key><string>Default-Landscape-736h</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key><string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key><string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key><string>{414, 736}</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key><string>Default-Portrait-736h</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key><string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key><string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key><string>{375, 667}</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key><string>Default-Portrait-667h</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: This worked great until we needed split screen support and had to switch to a LaunchScreen.storyboard. Unfortunately, it seems less flexible and we can't specify different images on an iPad for portrait and landscape modes.

Answer (score 2):

Just check this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27

You have to use @3x size image for start up image

Answer (score 1):

Details are already there, you just need to check the attribute inspector.

[image]